# Show that the relation $G(a, b) = 0$ yields $b$ as a function of $a$

Tags: real-analysis

For the equation, $$G(a,b)=\sin(a)+2\cos(b)− \frac{1}{2}$$ 
with $(a_0,b_0) = (\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{3\pi}{2})$.

Show that the relation $G(a, b) = 0$ yields $b$ as a function of $a$,  in a non-empty open neighborhood $N$ that contains $a_0$ and that $G(a_0,b_0) = 0$. 
 Denote the function by $g$ and compute $g'$ in $N$. Meanwhile, find the value $g′(a_0)$.

My thought: It is obvious that if you substitute $(\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{3\pi}{2})$ as $a$ and $b$ will yield 0, but how can i show the relation and it's an non=empty neighbourhood?